# Ошибка при создании объекта класса

Tags: c++, макросы, препроцессор

Всем привет. Только начал изучать C++, ранее только C#. Почему появляется ошибка?

```
   #include "Process.h"
    #include "cVehicle.h";
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    cVehicle veh;

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

        Attach();


    }
```

Ошибка (ругается на cVehicle veh;):

> Ошибка    C4430   отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int.
>   Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию

cVehicle.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "cVehicle.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Process.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class cVehicle {
public:
    void TestVoid() {
     cout << "i'm here!;
    }

    int test_int() {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

cVehicle.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

#ifndef cVehicle

#define cVehicle

using namespace std;

class cVehicle {
public:
    void TestVoid();

    int TestVoid();
};

#endif
```

Comment: В файле cVehicle.h объявлены две функции 'TestVoid', отличающиеся только возвращаемым значением. Это еще одна ошибка в дополнение к перечисленным в ответе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define cVehicle
```

приводит к тому, что

```
class cVehicle {
```

превращается в

```
class {
```

а

```
cVehicle veh;
```

в просто

```
veh;
```

Я так понимаю, вы хотели защитить заголовочный файл от повторного включения? В принципе, достаточно было

```
#pragma once
```

Но если уж очень хочется - то защищайте с помощью `#define`, но выбирайте имя макроса пострашнее :), чтоб ни с чем не совпало случайно... Что-то вроде

```
#ifndef cVehicle_INCLUDED__
#define cVehicle_INCLUDED__
```

(общих правил выбора имени *для защиты от повторного чтения* - помимо стандартных правил для имен идентификаторов в языке - нет).

Comment: Общие правила есть: не начинать с двух подчеркиваний, не начинать с подчеркивания и заглавной буквы. Такие имена зарезервированы для имплементаций компилятора.

Comment: @alexolut Это общие правила выбора имени для идентификатора, а не конкретно для защиты от повторения. В любом случае спасибо, я уточнил ответ.